# Integrating R Shiny app with SQL database

Tags: sql, r, database, shiny

Kind of a broad set of questions but:

I built a Shiny app in R and I've been testing it using a .csv file I downloade from a database. I want to integrate the app with that SQL database I download the .csv file from such that the app runs on and lives on the same server. What's the best way to do this? Does the Shiny app need its own container? Can it just be hosted on a server with a SQL or API connection facilitated through dplyr?

Comment: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/overview.html

Comment: https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/

Comment: *"the app runs on and lives on the same server"* ... are you talking about installing `shiny-server` (or `rstudio-connect`) on the same machine, and have its connections effectively use `127.0.0.1` for db connectivity? Or are you asking if it's possible to "serve" shiny content out of a database?

Comment: @r2evans I'm not exactly sure. The database lives on a protected server and I'm wondering if the Shiny app can be installed and run there / pull data from that SQL database using dplyr in .csv form?

Comment: You need to install a *shiny server*, somewhere. While it might benefit from being on the same actual host, there can be consequences (if the dbms is resource-heavy). Regardless, you need to distinguish between a "shiny app" and a "shiny server"; the former cannot live without the latter (*period*). The shiny/dbms benefits from being very *close* (network-wise), but if your queries do not return gobs of data then it doesn't impact *a lot*.

Comment: @r2evans okay, cool. thanks for explaining. so would the shiny server need to first data from the SQL database and then pass that to the app?

Comment: The "shiny server" will pull no data from the database, that is the responsibility of the "shiny app" hosted on the shiny server. Check Phil's first comment for a starting point, my first comment for generic database ops in R (not sure if that link is helpful or if you are already comfortable with `DBI`).

Comment: @r2evans cool-- so does the shiny server / app need their own container?

Comment: "container" suggests docker or some other virtualization engine, which is certainly an option but is not required. It is a server. Servers can run on bare metal, in a container, or as a "snap", depending on the OS and your preferences. If you're working in a docker (or docker-like) environment where the DBMS is on one host or container, and (as examples) you have Redis in a container and php-nginx in a third container, then **yes**, shiny-server goes in its own container.